# In SQL is there a way to partition by a value if it's not continuous

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to do the rank the values over a partition with two columns. `col1` will be the key and `col2` will be some value that is also going to be used in `ORDER BY`. I would like to start a new partition only when `col2` is discontinued. For example, I would like to do the following:

```
+------+------+------+
| col1 | col2 | rank |
+------+------+------+
| a    |    1 |    1 |
| a    |    2 |    2 |
| a    |    3 |    3 |
| a    |    9 |    1 |
| a    |   10 |    2 |
| b    |    1 |    1 |
| b    |    2 |    2 |
| b    |    8 |    1 |
+------+------+------+
```

Thinking somewhere in lines of 
`SELECT col1, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY col1, SOMETHING HERE??? ORDER BY col2 DESC)`

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to enumerate by "islands" of adjoining sequential values.  You can do so with a simple observation:  subtracting a sequence from `col2` will be constant for each group.  So, let's use this observation:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by col1, grp order by col1) as rnk
from (select t.*,
             (col2 - row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col2)) as grp
      from t
     ) t
```